# Range is printed at the end of the "each" iteration

Tags: ruby

What I'll show is a fulish function, but it's only to explain my problem in a simple way. If I solve the problem in this function, I solved the problem in the original code too.

The problem is simple, and probably the solution too, but I'm new in Ruby and have this doubt. I want to print the values in a range:

```
def test
  (0...5).each do |i|
    puts i
  end
end
```

When I call the function, the result that I want is

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

but the result that I have is

```
0
1
2
3
4
0...5
```

Why this `0...5` is printed together? How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i don't think the `0..5` is being produced as part of the `puts` call. Rather, when you call this in your REPL (irb, pry, rails console, etc), you're seeing because it's the last returned value in your code.

Let me show you an example.

Say I save a file called `test.rb` with the following content:

```
1.upto(5).each { |i| puts i }
```

If I call `ruby test.rb`, I see the expected output,

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

If I open irb and run `require("./test.rb")`, I see the same output.

It's only when I paste the code into irb that I see the additional output (`=> 0...5`). So I would just ignore this.

Comment: I don't have the same behavior here. If I save only my loop in a rb file, like you did, I've the desired output. But if I put them inside a function, the range is printed again. That when I call ``ruby test.rb`` in my linux terminal.

Comment: I just tested that. putting `def foo; 1upto(5).each { |i| puts i }; end; foo` in a file and calling it with `ruby test.rb` just prints the number 1 through 5. The main point I'm trying to make is that in a REPL (like IRB), you will see the result of `puts/print` calls in addition to the returned values of every function.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36732797/3437900)

Whenever any expression is executed in `IRB` sessions, it will also print the value returned by every expression executed.

In case of method definition it returns the `method_name` just defined.

```
  > def my_method
 ?>   puts 'this is my method'
 ?> end
 => :my_method
```

You see, the `:my_method` is printed

When the method is invoked, it should print the value returned by the method execution i.e. response of the last expression in the method i.e. `puts`

```
  > my_method
this is my method
 => nil
```

but it printed `nil` because `puts` [always returns](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts) `nil`. I mentioned this because normally developers are astonished when they see their methods returning `nil` unexpectedly.